# Conditional continuous distributions not knowing joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I'm struggling to find the joint distribution $P(X\le x, Y=0)$, where $X\sim$ Unif$[0,1]$ and $Y\sim$ Bernoulli$(X)$. I can compose

$$P(X\le x, Y=0)=P(X\le x\mid Y=0)\cdot P(Y=0)$$,
but this is where I hit a snag. How do I solve $P(X\le x\mid Y=0)$ when I don't know $P(X≤x, Y=0)$, and the definition of continuous conditional distributions uses it? I think it's gotta be like $\int_0^x$ of something, but I don't know what to integrate. Any intuition here?

Comment: what are you given exactly about $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: $X$ is Unif[0,1] and $Y$ is Bernoulli with $p=X$

Comment: Since $Y$ distribution depends on $X$, start with $P(X\le x,Y=0)=P(Y=0|X\le x)P(X\le x)$

Comment: Okay but then after resolving $P(X\leq x)=1$ I'm still left with $P(X\leq x, Y=0) = P(Y = 0|X\leq x)$, which runs into the same problem that the definition of a conditional distribution is dependent on the joint distribution, which I don't know. I understand that $P(Y=0|X=x)=x$, but I'm not sure how to account for the less than part of the inequality

Comment: Please state the actual problem statement in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given a marginal density and a conditional pmf, that is

$$f_X(x)=\mathbb{1}_{[0;1]}(x)$$

and

$$p_{Y|X}(y|x)=x^y(1-x)^{1-y}$$

where $y=0;1$ and $x \in [0;1]$

thus the requested joint distribution is, using the definition

$$P(X\leq x;Y=0)=\int_0^x(1-t)dt=x-\frac{x^2}{2}$$